# When asking 'What is your name?' or 'What is your job?', why is it 'は' not 'か'?

Tags: particles, syntax, particle-は, ellipsis, questions

As per the title, when asking 'What is your name?' or 'What is your job?', why is it 'は' not 'か'? For example, we are taught this:

> おしごとは。
>   'What is your job?'

But I don't understand why it isn't this?

> あなたはしごとですか。
>   'What is your job?'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

お仕事は？ *Oshigoto wa?* is basically short for お仕事は何ですか？ *Oshigoto wa nan desu ka?*

あなたは仕事ですか？ *Anata wa shigoto desu ka?* means "Are you work?" and is nonsensical†.

は *wa* (not わ BTW) is the topic marker.* Just asking 〜は basically means "About ~..." and only hints at the actual question. Leaving things unspoken is a very typical thing in Japanese. *"About (your) work..."* is the subtle, polite way to ask "What is your work?".

Simply 仕事か？ *Shigoto ka?* would mean something like "Work, eh?" and is more of an exclamation than a question. It's also rather rough, at the very least *not polite*.

---

* That's why あなたは仕事ですか？ *Anata wa shigoto desu ka?* marks "you" as the topic and is wrong. It's basically saying *"About you, are you work?"*

†  In the context of this question at least, see comments.

Comment: Just would like to add to this. Couldn't あなたは仕事ですか？  also be interpreted as "Are you currently working/at work?" depending on the context.

Comment: @phirru, may be there is some more sense of using "Are you going to work?" like in "私は買い物に行きますけど、あなたは仕事ですか？"

Comment: That's the sort of usage I was thinking about. (Alhough the use of "あなた" itself is very rare in normal Japanese). Possibly could be used on the phone: 「（あなた、今）仕事ですか？」

Comment: Sure, *"anata wa shigoto desu ka"* can have any number of meanings, but certainly nothing useful in the context of the question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually makes sense once you read it out loud. On a side note, good to see a few SO users jumping on this exchange too.

Answer (score 6):

It is more polite if you omit or not using straight form when asking personal things.

> お　しごと　は

means

> お しごと は なんですか？

And following is not correct

> あなた は しごと です か

which means "Are you a work?"